# Probability of getting heads with less than $n$ tosses?

Tags: probability, statistics

What is the probability of getting heads with less than $n$ tosses?

Context:

I flip a coin until I get heads, after I get heads I stop.

I was wondering if there is a probability function on the number of coins I need to flip to get heads.

Attempt at the problem:

Probability of getting at least one head when $k$ tosses are made is $1-(1/2)^k$.

Probability of getting heads within $1$ toss is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Probability of getting heads within $\infty$ tosses is $1$.

From here I guessed that probability of getting at least $1$ head within $n$ tosses would be
$$1-\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2^k}.$$


Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also I saw that coin flip type questions is in the setting of Binomial distribution, how does one adjust it to fit the problem I am looking at.

For real life context, I started playing a gacha game  was wondering what the probability of getting the item from the gacha within a certain number of tries would be. And saw that it reduces to the coin flip problem ie binomial distribution. Was easy to calculate probabilities if I already knew how many boxes I would open, but in real life you don't know how many boxes you would open as one usually stops once they get the item.

Edit for better guess at answer:

Thanks to drhab for commenting about geometric distribution. Wiki tells us that the probability of the first success bein on the $k^{\text{th}}$ trial is
$$P(X=k)=\left(1-p\right)^{k-1}p$$
where $p$ is the probability of success on a single trial.

So for our problem the probability of needing $k$ tosses to get heads is
$$P(X=k)=\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k-1}\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}^k$$
and hence
$$P(X\leq n)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2}^k.$$

Comment: Google on *geometric distribution*.

Comment: Lol thanks a bunch @drhab. That was exactly what I was looking for. I will edit the with an answer once I try and grasp/apply the method.

Comment: What is the difference between getting at least one head "when $k$ tosses are made" and getting at least one head "within $n$ tosses"? I think your latter expression, $1-\sum_{k=1}^n{1\over2^k}$, is the probability of getting the *first* head on the $n$th toss.

Comment: @BarryCipra Yea the probability seems to be same. But the questions seem to be different. I dont know if you are leading me to learn something about subtlety lol.

Comment: @AndyNguyen, One subtlety to be aware of: In your edit, you have correctly computed $P(X\le n)$, but what you have asked for is actually $P(X\lt n)$. You can understand the difference by letting $n=1$ and asking if it's possible to get a heads by tossing a coin *less than once* -- which is to say, not at all!

Comment: The probability of "getting heads for the first time on the nth flip" is the same as the probability of "getting n-1 tails in a row" which is $(1/2)^{n-1}$.

Comment: @user247327, you are omitting what happens on the $n$th toss itself!

Comment: No, on the nth toss, we **must** get  heads with probability 1.